# How to I check if my camera is working properly?

Tags: equipment-damage, travel

I have a sony rx100II. I have recently sent it by parcel delivery together with some other items.

When I got the parcel some of the items had physical damages. The camera was inside a box, padded, but I would like to make sure everything is working properly. The other damages were quite significant which means something major must have happened to the parcel.

Is there a systematic way of checking a camera?

Answer (score 3):

As long as it still takes photographs and the files don't look crazy there are only mechanical parts you could check:

- does the lens extend and retract without making strange noise?
- does focusing and stabilization (if camera has one) work without making strange noise?
- do all buttons work?
- is the battery door opening and closing?
- internal flash unit working properly?
- Display OK?

Normally there is not too much that should be able to break only because the camera's box was handled a little bit rough.

Comment: Thanks! nice list. How would you check stabilization?

Comment: @nsn: Turn it on, take multiple pictures with a low shutter speed (1/10 s or so), turn it off, again take multiple pictures and compare results. This of course is a little bit erratic but one should be able to get an impression if the IS is still doing something or not.

Comment: ... "without making a horrible noise" at least for items 1&2

Comment: @Chris H: Thanks for your comment. Good point! I have added it.